# not able to forward request from one webApp to another WebApp

Tags: java

I'm getting the following error when i'm trying to forward the request from one webApplication to the other webApplication using the following code,through filter:

```
ServletConfig sc=getServletConfig(); 
javax.servlet.ServletContext otherCtx = sc.getServletContext().getContext("/pharmacy");
otherCtx.getRequestDispatcher(forwardUrl.substring(forwardUrl.indexOf('/',1))).forward(pRequest, pResponse);
```

But i'm able to see a blank page. can anyone please give a sloution..

```
ERROR [[default]] Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException  at atg.servlet.minimal.MinimalContainerUtil.dispatchToDynamoPipeline(MinimalContainerUtil.java:334)     at atg.servlet.GenericRequestDispatcher.forward(GenericRequestDispatcher.java:534)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you under Tomcat?
If so, in your context xml file, add an attribute : crossContext=true

Answer (score 0):

If `/pharmacy` is in a different web-app, your filter won't know anything about it, so won't be able to do a server side redirect to it.

You may be better trying to do a client side redirect to get to the new web-app using `response.sendRedirect`